# Word to specify that a tree has arbitrary numbers of branches, as opposed to a binary tree

Tags: terminology, trees

What do you call a tree where each node has an arbitrary number of children (i.e. not necessarily 2)?

I'm trying to research some algorithms online, and Google keeps returning results for binary trees when I specify just "tree". I'm looking for a word I can add to my search terms to specify arbitrary branch counts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "tree", you refer to any kind of tree. Maybe "ordinary tree" if you want to emphasize over the fact that it can be any tree, but that is not necessary.

Binary tree, ternary tree, tress of a specific height, are all subsets of the set of "trees", that consists of a special kind of graphs (once again, when I said graphs, I am referring to all graphs, I don't need to explicitly say that).

Comment: Thanks... yeah I think I'm out of luck with these searches, because these trees are just called "trees". It looks like the best I can do with Google is just "tree -binary" and cross my fingers that there won't be significant collateral damage.

Comment: If you want to confuse people, you can also call it a generalized list :-D

Comment: Well, I seem to be having slightly more success by looking at search results for "tree -binary", and then again for "acyclic connected graph".

Comment: That's the definition of a tree. A tree is an acyclic connected graph. There's nothing special about it and it doesn't say anything more.

Comment: -1 because the other answers actually answer the question, unlike this too soon accepted answer.

Comment: And why my answer doesn't actually answer the question? He asks how to call a general tree, I said there is no special name, it is simply a tree.

Comment: @Pieter I accepted this because it answers my question: There isn't really a special word for it. It's what I suspected, I was just hoping for some CS word that wasn't in my vocabulary, but there isn't one. This answer also indirectly led to me just searching for acyclic connected graphs. I find this answer sufficient. I find the other answers to be excellent as well.

Comment: @Paul92 you say there is no term for it yet there is: "Directed Rooted Tree", k-ary tree .... etc.

Comment: A k-ary tree is a (rooted) tree in which each node has no more than k childs (e.g. binary tree for k=2, ternary tree for k=3, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree). A directed rooted tree is a tree where one node has been designated as root (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29#Rooted_tree). There are trees that do not have a known root and have an arbitrary number of nodes (i.e. they are neither rooted nor k-ary), which means that your examples are just specific examples of trees.

Answer (score 6):

*Binary* trees are the most common kind of trees, but *ternary* trees also pop up sometimes. For generalized trees with (up to) *k* childs per node, the term [*k-ary* tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree) (or *n-ary* tree) is used.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, a [Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) is simply an (undirected or directed) acyclic graph.

If the tree has direction, so it is a *Directed Tree* (directed acyclic graph).

If a tree has a single root, it is a *Rooted Tree* (see also [Poly Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree)).

If it has both, it is a *Directed Rooted Tree*, which,

- if it all its directed edges lead away from the root, is an *[Arborescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory))*, or *Branching-Tree*, or *Out-Tree*, and,
- if it all directed edges lead to the root, it is an *Anti-Arborescence* or *In-Tree*

So, most of what we deal with in computer science is the  *Arborescence*, or *Branching-Tree*, or *Out-Tree*, which allows for any number of children at each branch.  (Still, we just call them "trees", so that doesn't help much with your searches...)

Comment: Great answer. Adding: From what I understand technically a single tree is a *connected* acyclic graph, to set it apart from a forest.